# Error in converting base64 string to image c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I want to display image on my web page and while clicking link button that should download. The image file stored stored as binary format in db. while converting base64 string to image it showing an error. Details are given below. Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Error:

[image]

Code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   if (!IsPostBack)
     {

      pdfDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_imgTableAdapter td;
      td = new pdfDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_imgTableAdapter();
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt = td.GetId();
      DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
      DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Id";
      DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
      DropDownList1.DataBind();
      DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("--Select Id--", ""));
     }

  }
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     pdfDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_imgTableAdapter td;
     td = new pdfDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_imgTableAdapter();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt = td.GetImg(int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
         byte[] img2 = (byte[])row["img"];
         string base2 = Convert.ToBase64String(img2);
         Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base2;
       }     
   }

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        string sFile = Image1.ImageUrl;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFile))
        {
            return;
        }
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(sFile)); // error popup here
        if (!fi.Exists)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFile))
        {
            // check if the file is an image
            NameValueCollection imageExtensions = new NameValueCollection();
            imageExtensions.Add(".jpg", "image/jpeg");
            imageExtensions.Add(".gif", "image/gif");
            imageExtensions.Add(".png", "image/png");
            if (imageExtensions.AllKeys.Contains(fi.Extension))
            {
                Response.ContentType = imageExtensions.Get(fi.Extension);
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fi.Name);
                Response.TransmitFile(fi.FullName);
                Response.End();
            }
            Response.Redirect(sFile);
        }
```

Aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"> </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Show" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Download</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
```

Sql query1:

```
SELECT Id FROM tbl_img
```

Sql query1:

```
SELECT img FROM tbl_img WHERE (Id = @Id)
```

DB:

[image]

O/P Screen:

[image]

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: MapPath doesn't work that way. It is only for server paths - a data URL is not a path.

Comment: what is coming in `ImageUrl`??

Comment: Also - dataURL does not contain some of the data you want from the FileInformation such as filename or extension (although you can get extension from opening MIME type). If you're trying to use FileInfo for validation purposes, you need to use another method.

Comment: @binderbound : can you post any sample code.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the "download" link, you try to open the Image1.URL, which is a dataURL, not an actual path. This causes MapPath to fail.

The Reason why Image1.URL is a dataURL is that you set the image to a dataurl  when you click button 1 (show).

What you can do is parse the dataURL to a file and send that

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var data = Image1.ImageUrl.split('base64,')[1];
    File f = Parse.File("filename.jpg", {"base64": data});
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
    Response.WriteFile(f);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```